TypeScript import issue with npm package exporting custom errors
I have created an npm package where I defined custom error classes and exported them. However, when importing these classes into another project, TypeScript shows an error despite successful import.
Here's the structure of my npm package:
NotFoundError.ts:
import { CustomError } from "./custom-error";

export class NotFoundError extends CustomError {
  statusCode = 404;

  constructor() {
    let message = "Route not found";
    super(message);

    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, NotFoundError.prototype);
  }

  serializeErrors() {
    return [{ message: this.message }];
  }
}

CustomError.ts:
export abstract class CustomError extends Error {
  abstract statusCode: number;

  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, CustomError.prototype);
  }

  abstract serializeErrors(): { message: string; fields?: string }[];
}

index.ts:
export * from "./errors/custom-error";
export * from "./errors/not-found-error";

In another project, I installed this npm package and attempted to import the error classes:
import {
  CustomError,
  NotFoundError,
} from "@node/common";

Despite no errors being shown during import, when attempting to use the NotFoundError class like so:
throw new NotFoundError('error message')
TypeScript throws an error:
error TS2305: Module "@node/common" has no exported member 'NotFoundError'.
I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.
